# Detect if a host is connected (gadget mode)

Tags: pi-zero-w, gadget

**Device**: Raspberry Pi Zero W v1.1

**State**: Pi Zero is running in gadget mode, acting as a USB Mass Storage device (seen by / mounted on a MacBook Pro).

**Question**: What is the best way to detect whether or not the MacBook Pro is still connected / using the Pi as a Mass Storage device?

Ideally, either by polling or event trigger, I would like to know (within about ~5 seconds) if the User has either ejected the USB device or shut down the MacBook Pro ... at which point, I'd be able to execute some shell commands.

There is a similar question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68169/check-if-a-host-device-is-connected-to-pi-zero-gadget), but the author asks about collecting information about the connected host, which is unnecessary in my use-case.

I've tried using:

`cat /sys/class/udc/20980000.usb/state` ... and, while it seems to pick up the change from `not attached` ==> `configured` (when I plug Pi into my MacBook), it doesn't pick up the change when I eject/disconnect (it seems to stay stuck in `configured` and never "drops back down" to `not attached`).  This seems to be related to a known issue (mentioned in [here](http://patches.linaro.org/patch/86704/#368083)).

Comment: Would the change to the `state` file not require some input from your Mac?

Comment: @Seamus, I’m not sure what your asking. If you look at the article I reference, the behavior (not toggling back to “not attached”) is / was not correct.  I contacted the author and he did eventually create a patch, but I don’t know how to apply it to the Linux kernel (currently working to learn how).

Comment: I was mostly curious; never really thought much about how the 'plugged in device` sees this. Initial thought was that only the 'plugged into device` had visibility of status, but apparently that's not so! Wrt a patch finding its way into the RPi kernel anytime soon, my advice is "don't hold your breath". I submitted a bug report once & it seems a black hole from my perspective. But perhaps [@dougie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/94397/dougie) has better insights? You might try reaching out to him.

Answer (score -1):

Run `udevamdin monitor` on your Raspverry Pi Zero.

You can monitor the event.

So it would help if you did research `udev` things...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).